# Java scripting API fails to retrieve engine by name

Tags: java, scripting, jython, rhino

I'm trying to find installed scripting engines with the Java Scripting API but something is going wrong.

In this demo program I used the ***ScriptEngineManager*** to retrieve factories and list all the engines I have. After that I try to get it by name, but the result is null.

```
 public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    List<ScriptEngineFactory> factories = manager.getEngineFactories();

    for (ScriptEngineFactory factory : factories) {
        System.out.println("\nName : " + factory.getEngineName());
        System.out.println("Version : " + factory.getEngineVersion());
        System.out.println("Language name : " + factory.getLanguageName());
        System.out.println("Language version : " + factory.getLanguageVersion());
        System.out.println("Extensions : " + factory.getExtensions());
        System.out.println("Mime types : " + factory.getMimeTypes());
        System.out.println("Names : " + factory.getNames());
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName(factory.getEngineName());
        if (engine == null) {
            System.out.println("Impossible to find the engine with name " + factory.getEngineName()+"\n");
        }

    }
   }
 }
```

and the result is :

> Version : 1.7 release 3 PRERELEASE
>
> Language name : ECMAScript
>
> Language version : 1.8
>
> Extensions : [js]
>
> Mime types : [application/javascript, application/ecmascript, text/javascript, text/ecmascript]
>
> Names : [js, rhino, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript]
>
> Impossible to find the engine with name Mozilla Rhino

---

> Name : jython
>
> Version : 2.7.0
>
> Language name : python
>
> Language version : 2.7
>
> Extensions : [py]
>
> Mime types : [text/python, application/python, text/x-python, application/x-python]
>
> Names : [python, jython]
>
> Impossible to find the engine with name jython

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation of the `getnames()` method of `ScriptEngineFactory`:

> Returns an immutable list of short names for the ScriptEngine, which may be used to identify the ScriptEngine by the ScriptEngineManager.

that is, one of these names must be used:

```
...
System.out.println("Names : " + factory.getNames());
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName(factory.getNames().get(0));
...
```

Comment: it's work for the first engine **Mozila Rhino** but not for the **Jython** engine,the use of factory.getNames() is a solution among others ok, what I could not understand is why it's work for one and not for other, should I use install something(interpreter) on my machine to get the jython work ?

Comment: very strange indeed, Sorry, I do not have/use Jython - I have no idea how it must be installed

Comment: you could try getting the engine by `getEngineByMimeType("text/python")`

Comment: Or you could try `factory.getScriptEngine();`.